# Apply css rule only if next div exists - Just CSS not javascript

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to apply the CSS rule only if we detect that a div follows the rule?

Example

```
<div class="div1">...</div>
<div class="div2">..</div>
```

CSS Example

```
(if exist div2) .div2 .div1 (aply rule css to div1) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: You can use [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if/) to make a conditional statement in css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class in combination with the [next sibling
selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Next-sibling_combinator):

```css
.div1:has(+ .div2) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">...</div>
<div class="div2">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
div1:has(+ div2) {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: `.div2`, the above won;t work

Answer (score -1):

In this example, the CSS rule .div2 + .div1 targets a .div1 that directly follows a .div2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        /* Your default styles for .div1 */
        .div1 {
            background-color: blue;
        }

        /* Additional styles for .div1 when it follows .div2 */
        .div2 + .div1 {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="div1">This is div1</div>
    <div class="div2">This is div2</div>
    <div class="div1">This is another div1</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not valid :(